# MySQL PHP Game After Insert Trigger Error

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am creating a simple text-based RPG using PHP and MySQL and am running into a strange error when attempt to utilize an AFTER INSERT trigger.

After I insert a new creature into the creatures table I want to use a trigger to also insert a new record into the store table with loot information pertaining to the creature I added.  Specifically, when I insert a record in creatures I want it to take 'gloot' and put that into the store table.

Code for creatures table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `creatures` (
      `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
      `hpoints` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `maxhp` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `attack` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `defense` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `experience` int(3) NOT NULL,
      `level` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `gloot` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `gold` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      `isloot` mediumint(3) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

Code for store table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `stats` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statadd` smallint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `randid` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And finally, here is the trigger code

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS itemToStore
CREATE TRIGGER itemToStore
AFTER INSERT ON `creatures`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (New.gloot != “”) THEN
INSERT INTO  `store`  (`name`, `statadd`, `price`, `amount`, `randid`)
VALUES('New.gloot', '0', '0',’0’, ROUND( 100000000 * RAND( ) ));
END IF;
END;
$$
```

So, what I am saying is, if the gloot is not empty then insert that into the store table.

The trigger is added fine, but the error that is raised after I insert into the creatures table is a strange one.  I get:

> MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'â€œâ€

And for completeness, here is the insert statement I am using:

```
INSERT INTO  `legends`.`creatures` (

`id` ,
`name` ,
`hpoints` ,
`maxhp` ,
`attack` ,
`defense` ,
`experience` ,
`level` ,
`gloot` ,
`gold` ,
`isloot`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  'dragon',  '200',  '200',  '10',  '10',  '1',  '1',  'Dragon Bones',  '250',  '50'
)
```

*Phew* That was a lot.  Thank you kindly for your time!

Comment: try replacing the quotes `”` and `’` with **`'`.**

Comment: `IF (New.gloot != “”)` looks suspicious it should be `""`

Comment: Could also be a character set problem. Make sure EVERYTHING, EVERYWHERE is ALWAYS set to UTF-8 (or whatever your preferred charset is). Easy to forget one little element in the default charset and screw everything up.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER itemToStore AFTER INSERT ON creatures FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF ' at line 2`  is what I now get after I changed the funny looking quotes to `""`

Comment: Dropping the backticks (which aren't necessary anyway) might make your messages clearer, considering that on Stack Exchange, backticks are used to make a `code-like block like this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the quotes `”` and `’` with `'`.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS itemToStore $$

CREATE TRIGGER itemToStore AFTER INSERT ON `creatures`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF (NEW.gloot <> '') 
   THEN
      INSERT INTO  `store`  (`name`, `statadd`, `price`, `amount`, `randid`)
      VALUES (NEW.gloot, '0', '0','0', ROUND( 100000000 * RAND( ) ));
   END IF;
END;
$$
```

You also forgot to add the `$$` after the `drop` command.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Must be because I originally wrote the trigger in Word.  Gave me the funny quotes and such.  Just tested and it looks great, thank you very much for your time!